# Run AutoIt file with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I want to run my autoIt `.exe` file in ruby code. My file is present on desktop.
Please help guide me how to run an .exe file generated by AutoIT tool in a Selenium Ruby Webdriver script ?

My scenario is that I need to upload a file by clicking a Flash button, then select a file in the "Open" window popup. However, Selenium cannot interact with a window popup, so I used AutoIT tool to fill the file path and generated to a .exe file. The thing I want to do is that now I want Selenium will run the exe file generated by AutoIT tool after "Open" window popup displayed.
Beneath is my code:

```
$driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :ff
  $driver.get "http://url/uploadform/contactform.php"
  $driver.manage.window.maximize
 $driver.find_element(:xpath,".//input[@id='photo']").send_keys("C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/logo_icon.png")
  $driver.find_element(:xpath,".//input[@id='photo']").click

  # au3=WIN32OLE.new("C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\test.exe")

file = File.open("C:/Users/Aditya/Desktop/test.exe", "r")

contents = file.read
```

Here test.exe is my autoIt file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem is...? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You haven't told us enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into one of the following commands:

- system("command")
- `command` (backticks) or `%x{}` syntax
- spawn("command")

They differ by what they return and how they are launched.

```
command = "C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\test.exe"

system(command)
%x`#{command}`
spawn(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for swift response

Answer (score 0):

I have used Process in case AutoIt but if anyone wants to open batch file he can use answer mentioned by @Uzbekjon in above comment.

One liner answer to my question is:
Process.exec("Path of auto it file")